# Ruby on Rails NameError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm making a new app for following user and I get some troubles. This is my error:

```
NameError in Welcome#sucess
Showing ../welcome/sucess.html.erb where line #13 raised:
uninitialized constant User::FollowingRelation
Extracted source (around line #13):

10: <br />
11: Following
12: <ul>
13:   <% @user.following.each do |u| %>
14:     <li><%= link_to u.username, u %></li>
15:   <% end %>
16: </ul>
```

I can find User::FollowingRelation in my code:

*My user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :pass, :username
  # Who am I following?
  has_many :following_relations, :foreign_key => :follower_id
  has_many :following, :through => :following_relations 
  # Who am I followed by?
  has_many :follower_relations, :class_name => "Relation", :foreign_key => :following_id
  has_many :followers, :through => :follower_relations

  validates :username, :pass, :presence => true
  validates :username, :pass, :length => { :minimum => 4 }
  validates :username, :uniqueness => true


    def self.login(username,pass)
    user = find_by_username(username) and user = find_by_pass(pass)   
    if user.nil?
      return nil
    else
      return user
    end
    end
end
```

*relaion model

```
class Relation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :follower, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :following, :class_name => "User"
end
```

*Action sucess

```
def sucess
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
   @relation = Relation.new
 end
```

I'm new in Ruby on Rails, so please help me:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify this line:

```
has_many :following_relations, :foreign_key => :follower_id
```

To:

```
has_many :following_relations, class_name: 'Relation', :foreign_key => :follower_id
```

Comment: i have new error :)) but i think i can fix that. Thank you!!